# Iterating through and selecting nth element in multiple lists of lists - python 2

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, loops

I have multiple lists of lists. I need to get the 2nd element of each inner list and make multiple new lists composed of these 2nd elements.

Sample data:

```
for item in list:
   x = fpp.table
   print x

[['hello', 'mum'],['goodbye', 'dad']]
[['3', '6', '9'], ['2', '4', '6']]
```

So with this data I want to turn it into the two following lists:

```
['mum','dad']
['6','4']
```

Comment: `[x[1] for x in lst]`? Are these separate lists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets try making a function like this:

```
def secondElement(list):
    secondL = []
    for item in list:
        secondL.append(item[1])
    print (secondL)
```

This should do the job for  getting the 2nd element of the every integrated sub-list from the main list. Hope this is what you were looking for!

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is correct. However, the most Pythonic (IMO) way to do that is (BTW, you should avoid to name your variable `list` since this is a type in Python) to use a list comprehension:

```
[elt[1] for elt in my_list]
```

If you want to get the second element of each list only when the list has at least two elements (otherwise, the previous code would crash), you can add a condition to the list comprehension:

```
[elt[1] for elt in my_list if len(elt) >= 2]
```